# Splitting string after specific character in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have for example this string **name-surname-15A-15B** and for example if I want to get the last segment(which is 15B) I can use the following query:

```
Select right(Code, charindex('-', reverse(Code)) - 1) as segment From MyTable
```

But how can I get string after specific dash for example the second one which will return 15A-15B ?

Comment: Attention: Although this is a duplicate question one warning: The linked questions provides some very old and outdated answers. They were good when they were written, but it is a good idea to search for newer / more active answers...

Answer (score 3):

Just another option is `ParseName()`  provided the segments don't exceed 4

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(50)='name-surname-15A-15B'

Select ParseName(Replace(@S,'-','.'),1)
```

**Returns**

```
15B
```

For last two positions

```
Declare @S varchar(50)='name-surname-15A-15B'

Select ParseName(Replace(@S,'-','.'),2)
      +'-' 
      +ParseName(Replace(@S,'-','.'),1)
```

**Returns**

```
15A-15B
```

Comment: You've done it again :-D

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do it by using something like this.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( string , LEN(string) -  CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(string)) + 2  , LEN(string)  ) FROM SAMPLE;
```

Where `string` is the string you want to split.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that there will be 3, and only 3, hyphens (`-`) in the value of `Code`, you could do:

```
SELECT Code,
       RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code) - CI1.CI) AS C1,
       RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code) - CI2.CI) AS C2, --One you're after
       RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code) - CI3.CI) AS C3
FROM (VALUES ('name-surname-15A-15B')) V(Code)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-',V.Code))) CI1(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-',V.Code,CI1.CI+1))) CI2(CI)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-',V.Code,CI2.CI+1))) CI3(CI);
```

You can easily expand this for more than that; however, if you have quite a lot of delimiters, I'd suggest looking into a string splitter, and then using `FOR XML PATH`to concatenate the string back together. *Edit: Or `STRING_AGG`of you're using SQL Server 2017.*

Comment: I'd love to know what the downvote was for. Feedback is always appreciated. :)